# Qunit: ReferenceError: equals is not defined

Tags: javascript, qunit

Im QUnit newbie.

I created simple test but it fails with error: "ReferenceError: equals is not defined". My code is following:

simpleTests.js:

```
QUnit.test('isEven()', function (assert) {
    equals(2, 1, 'one equals one');
})
```

simpleTestRun.js:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>QUnit Test Suite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qunit/qunit.js"></script>
    <!-- Your JS library file goes here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="simple.js"></script>

    <!-- Your tests file goes here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="simpleTests.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="qunit-header">QUnit Test Suite</h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
    <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
</body>

</html>
```

What is wrong?

UPDATE1:
I doing QUnit test on local disc, not through web server. How it affect testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equal` (not `equals`) is a method of [assert](https://api.qunitjs.com/config/QUnit.assert/), so you have to use it like this:

```
QUnit.test('isEven()', function (assert) {
    assert.equal(2, 1, 'one equals one');
})
```

Comment: after update, there is error `TypeError: assert.equals is not a function`

Comment: it's `equal`, not `equals`, I fixed the code example